# Pregunta editada por el usuario ¿Qué hacer con la respuesta anterior?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ediciones

[La pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21735/listas-en-lenguaje-c/21746#21746) constaba en pedir consejos de cómo implementar un juego Solitario en `C`:

#### Pregunta original

> #### ''Solitario'' simple, con listas en Lenguaje C
>
> Es mas que quedo por si me pueden dar consejos de como implementarlo.Estoy empezando en este tema de las estructuras de datos, y se los agradecería mucho. El enunciado dice lo siguiente:
>   El tablero constará de seis columnas con cartas y un espacio para indicar cual es la carta al tope de la baraja.
>
> Ejemplo:"Tablero"
>   Siguiente carta: 7R
>
> 6N 5N KR 4N QR 2N.
>
> Las opciones son Poner carta en columna, mover carta desde columna, Siguiente carta.

Mi respuesta (que cuenta con una moderada aceptación) se basa en la petición original del usuario, el cuál pedía consejos para una implementación y yo di consejos en base a su pregunta. Pero mi respuesta ahora carece completamente de sentido ya que el usuario ha editado la pregunta al completo:

> #### Listas en Lenguaje C
>
> Estoy utilizando una lista circular para simular el mazo de cartas, las columnas del tablero, son lista enlazadas, ya las dos listas las tengo implementadas. Pero tengo dos dudas como le puede pasar por parámetro un array de caracteres (que serian las cartas "1R" - "4N"), y como puedo conectar varias listas enlazadas.

La pregunta ha pasado de ser una petición de consejo sobre una implementación concreta a ser una duda sobre listas enlazadas en `C` (pregunta que además no se entiende muy bien).

---

Es la primera vez que me encuentro con este caso y ando un poco descolocado ¿Qué debo hacer?:

- Borrar mi respuesta original y pedir al usuario que reformule la pregunta.
- Conservar la respuesta original y pedir al usuario que deje la pregunta original y formule una pregunta nueva.
- Otras opciones.

Comment: Yo haría un rollback de la pregunta y mantendría tu respuesta. Asimismo añadiría un comentario para el usuario que ha hecho la pregunta explicándole que si tiene otras preguntas *debe* publicar otra pregunta pero no modificarla para preguntar otra cosa. Iba a hacerlo ahora mismo pero prefiero saber qué dice @LuiggiMendoza antes que nada!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Es una buena respuesta y lo mejor para el sitio es que se mantenga... Le explicaría al usuario en muy buenos términos por qué debería haber hecho una nueva pregunta, luego rollback... Antes de que la edite de nuevo pidiendo consejos de cómo diseñar el mazo en Photoshop!

Comment: Nunca he hecho un rollback en ningún StackExchange. ¿Cómo se hace? ¿Copiopego la respuesta original y sobreescribo?

Comment: Para hacer un rollback, en la pregunta, selecciona "editada hace X", dónde te aparece el historial de revisiones. Des de ahí, al lado de cada revisión aparece la opción "revertir".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Felicitaciones por la medalla de "Limpieza" :-)

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se trata de ediciones que suplantan todo o la mayor parte del contenido de la pregunta por una pregunta nueva, lo mejor es avisarle al usuario que debería publicar una nueva pregunta con estas nuevas inquietudes. Luego, hacer rollback a la pregunta a la última edición que mantenía el contenido de la "primera" pregunta (por así decirlo). En caso que el usuario vuelva a editar la pregunta, lo mejor es no alterarse ni tomárselo a modo personal, sino más bien reportar la pregunta indicando lo sucedido, luego un moderador revisará el caso y actuará acorde a la situación.

Tengamos en mente siempre apoyar a los usuarios al buen uso del sitio.

---

Para hacer rollback de la pregunta, puedes seleccionar el historial de revisión de la pregunta, ubicarte en el número de edición correspondiente y seleccionar la opción "revertir".

Para más información, favor de remitirse a [¿Qué es una 'reversión'?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/7242).

Comment: Tarde, ya lo había hecho. Pero gracias ;P (¡espero haberlo hecho bien!)

Comment: Recuerda que puede que otros usuarios se encuentren en la misma situación. Las preguntas y respuestas no son solo para el presente sino para la posteridad también :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Entonces hemos actuado correctamente? ¡Genial! Gracias por la confirmación, no estaba 100% seguro.

Comment: @MiquelColl para servirlos

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He captado la indirecta y traducido el tema de los RollBacks =P

Comment: @MiquelColl gracias por el apoyo con  la traducción