# ¿Qué es una 'reversión'?

Tags: soporte, faq, ediciones

> De la pregunta original [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038)

¿Qué es una reversión? Veo que se menciona en [la medalla de limpieza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup), pero no entiendo lo que significa.

> Para más información, consulta [¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Adaptado a partir de la [respuesta original (*aceptada*)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876) a la pregunta *[What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876)*

## ¿Qué es una reversión?

Una reversión hace un par de cosas:

1. Lo más importante, una publicación vuelve a tener el texto que tenía en una versión anterior.
2. Cuando se revierte una publicación, la edición seleccionada aparece como la más reciente en el historial de revisiones.
3. Una reversión limpia los reportes ofensivos que pudiera tener la publicación que hayan sido emitidos luego de la revisión a la que se volvió.

---

## ¿Cómo se revierte una publicación a una versión anterior?

Puedes revertir una publicación dentro del historial de revisiones, al cual se puede acceder haciendo click al pie de la publicación, en donde dice cuándo fue editada.

> [image: editada <fecha>]

Dentro del [historial de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/21735/revisions) (ejemplo de una pregunta en concreto), se selecciona **`revertir`** en la versiones previa hacia la que se quiere volver. Ejemplo:

> [image: Historial de revisiones, mostrando dónde está el menú "revertir"]

Que luego se mostrará como si hubiese sido una nueva edición, mostrando el texto "Revertido a la revisión #":

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La publicación volverá al contenido que tenía en esa revisión, y se mostrará al usuario que realizó la reversión como el último editor de la publicación (no al editor de la versión a la que se volvió). La fecha de edición será la fecha de la reversión.

---

**Nota**: no hay forma de escribir un motivo para la reversión. Si se quisiera dejar un motivo para la reversión, se puede seleccionar **`editar`** en la revisión a la que se quiere ir, y anotar el motivo como resumen de la edición.