# ¿Cómo funciona "revertir"?

Tags: soporte

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32863/guardar-datos-en-archivos) el usuario pedía una respuesta en C++, de manera bastante *rara* lo cuál motivó la edición de la pregunta (el resaltado es mío):

> Buenas
>
> Necesito poder guardar varios datos en un .txt
>
> Pero no se como hacer porque al momento de guardar me guarda símbolos y no lo que quiero
>
> Así esta: fprintf (archivo, "%s", cliente, "%d", apartamento, "%d", npiso)
>
> Cliente es un string Apartamento y npiso son int
>
> **Esto es en c+++**

La pregunta tenía como etiqueta C++, pese a que el código usado pertenece a las librerías C, además el usuario especifica que el lenguaje usado es "*c+++*".

Se hizo una edición para dar formato a las partes de código de la pregunta y eliminar las partes redactadas *de manera extraña*:

> Necesito poder guardar varios datos en un .txt
>
> Pero no se como hacer porque al momento de guardar me guarda símbolos y no lo que quiero
>
> Así esta: `fprintf (archivo, "%s", cliente, "%d", apartamento, "%d", npiso)`
>
> `cliente` es un `string`
>
> `apartamento` y `npiso` son `int`

La edición me parece correcta y necesaria, esta edición conserva la etiqueta C++.

---

En la siguiente edición se substituye la etiqueta C++ por la de C; esta edición opino que es incorrecta ya que el usuario preguntó sobre C++ (aún usando librerías C) así que me dispuse a revertir esta última edición pero no es posible (no aparece el enlace "revertir" en la última edición).

- ¿Qué se necesita para que una pregunta sea revertible?
- ¿La reversión es sólo posible al cabo de un tiempo o debería estar disponible de manera inmediata? (si la pregunta cumple los requerimientos para ser revertible).

Comment: En este caso concreto, y teniendo en cuenta el contenido y nivel de la pregunta, parece muy posible que el usuario se confundiera con la etiqueta o ignorase las diferencias entre C y C++. El suponer que el usuario etiquetó correctamente me parece *pecar* de exceso de confianza. El cambio de etiqueta fue, como dices, para adecuarla al contenido *real* de la pregunta; si hubiera estado etiquetada desde un principio como **C**, ¿la habrías cambiado a **C++**?

Comment: No supongo que el usuario etiquetase correctamente. Lo deduzco del hecho de que escribió que la pregunta era *c+++*. También puede ser *exceso de confianza* creer que el usuario etiquetó incorrectamente, por ello me baso en lo que el usuario escribió no en lo que supongo que quería decir. SI la etiqueta original fuese C, la habría dejado como C.

Comment: Ese es mi punto, que si hubiera sido **C** desde un principio, este *intercambio educado de opiniones* ni siquiera existiría. Es decir, nadie se habría planteado reetiquetarla, mientras que, al etiquetarla como **C++**, si surge esa duda.

Comment: @Trauma el problema es que el código es válido tanto en C como en C++ por lo tanto, lo adecuado (desde mi punto de vista) no es **suponer** lo que el usuario quería si no respetar lo que el usuario **escribió**: que en este caso fue una etiqueta C++ y un "*Esto es en c+++*".

Comment: Tienes razón, el código es válido en **ambos** lenguajes. Voto por retiquetarla con **C++** **C**  ;-)

Comment: @Trauma en otros casos, yo mismo he re-etiquetado de C++ a C (o eliminado una de las dos etiquetas en [preguntas doblemente etiquetadas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/malos-etiquetados-dudosos)) cuando no había dudas de que el usuario hubiera hecho mal el etiquietado; aquí, discrepo totalmente de que el usuario quisiera decir C.

Comment: Me has convencido, es correcta la etiqueta **C++**. Pero soy más de **C** *a pelo*. Me resisto a decirle adiós a tan bonita etiqueta, **C**. En fín, ... Sigo votando como reetiquetarla con ambas ;-)

Comment: *No te preocupes*, hay decenas de oportunidades de re-etiquetado de C a C++ y viceversa; no le quites ojo a la pareja porque semanalmente salen varios candidatos (yo de vez en cuando filtro preguntas con ambas etiquetas y me encuentro muchos etiquetados dudosos o confusos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta información se encuentra en: [¿Qué es una 'reversión'?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/127)

---

Sobre el historial de revisiones, se debe seleccionar la revisión **hacia la cual** se quiere revertir. Por ejemplo, si sólo hubo 3 revisiones, deberías seleccionar `revertir` sobre la segunda edición.

En este caso en particular, sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se revierte **HACIA** otra revisión. Al hacer click en donde está la flecha, vuelve a ese estado.

No obstante, en estos casos te recomiendo comentar con prudencia y asegurarse de que todos los involucrados puedan llegar a entender en conjunto el porqué de la reversión, evitando cualquier posible conflicto.

Comment: La que quiero revertir es la de Trauma (que me parece incorrecta), no la de aldanux  (que me parece correcta). La edición de Trauma no tiene el enlace a revertir.

Comment: Es exactamente a lo que me refiero. Se revierte **HACIA** otra revisión. Si hacés click en donde está la flecha, vuelve a ese estado.

Comment: ¡Aaaaah! Gracias por la aclaración :)