# ¿Qué es un reporte en disputa?

Tags: soporte, faq, reportes

Estaba revisando mi historial de reportes y me fijé que dos de ellos están **en disputa**, los reportes son antiguos.

Aquí muestro los reportes en disputa
[image]

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Tendremos que empezar a solicitar investigación para las preguntas de Meta :) ¿Has mirado en [meta.se]? Allí está explicado jeje

Comment: @fedorqui es muy probable que sí, pero en inglés. Creo que conviene que exista la contraparte en español también.

Comment: @Luiggi ya, ya, absolutamente de acuerdo. Mi punto es que al fin y al cabo lo que hará quien contesté será traducir [ese artículo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/209901), bastante fácil de encontrar. De ahí que sugiera al OP que haga la búsqueda y lo publique él mismo, incluso como FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**En disputa**" es el el término medio: luego de ser revisado, no se definió como *útil*, ni fue *rechazado*. El nombre se puede malinterpretar, pero realmente Los reportes en disputa no suman en tu puntaje hacia más reportes por día (o hacia una advertencia o un ban de reportes).

**Casos:**

- Reportes de "no es una respuesta" o "muy baja calidad" en los que al final de la revisión se definió no eliminar (hubo opiniones diferentes). Esto es el resultado de la cola de revisión de Baja Calidad en la que se definió que "Se ve bien".

  - Incluso si un moderador ♦ lo cierra desde la cola de Baja Calidad como "Se ve bien" (en vez de decidirlo en la interfaz de reportes), el reporte se determina "en disputa".

- Reportes de "contenido no deseado" o "irrespetuoso o abusivo" que son *despejados* por un moderador ♦. Es decir, que no encontró motivos para penalizar al usuario que reportaste, pero sí encontró alguna evidencia o un motivo que haya justificado tu reporte. Es el caso en el que un moderador ♦ opina que no se debe penalizar a ninguno de los dos, haya o no una acción posterior del moderador ♦ sobre el caso.

  - Como estos reportes pueden implicar una penalidad de -100 sobre un usuario y aplicar medidas anti-spam sobre la publicación, uno que fue marcado como *útil*, *rechazado* o que fue *retractado* puede ser modificado retroactivamente. Puede suceder si la publicación entrara una segunda vez en la cola (por otros reportes), en donde un moderador ♦ puede marcar a *todos* los reportes de este tipo como *en disputa*. No obstante, una vez que fueron definidos como *en disputa*, no pueden ser cambiados.
- Reportes de "contenido no deseado" o "irrespetuoso o abusivo" en publicaciones que son [revertidas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/127).

---

Referencias:

- [Reportar Publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- *[What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/304899)*
- *[What happens when I flag a posted answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253244/304899)*

Comment: Gracias @mariano, otra pregunta: Estos reportes en disputa son puestos en ese estado por moderadores o por la comunidad?

Comment: @JuanPinzón Puede ser por ambos. El primer caso es por la comunidad, el segundo por un moderador.

Comment: ¿Pueden cambiar de estado en algún momento y dejar de estar en disputa? Si es así, ¿Quiénes pueden cambiarlo?

Comment: @ArtEze no, una vez se resolvió, un reporte no puede cambiar de estado.

Comment: @ArtEze Recién lo pregunté en *[Could a flag status change? (revisited)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295938/304899)*. No se puede jamás, salvo una única excepción: un reporte de spam/abusivo puede cambiar retroactivamente de útil/rechazado -> en disputa, sólo cuando la publicación entra una segunda vez en la cola y un moderador marca a *todos* los reportes en disputa (y no se puede en el sentido inverso).