# ¿Es posible cancelar una revisión de una edición sugerida?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

Estaba revisando una [edición sugerida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/53409) y le di aprobar la edición sin querer, pues lo que quería era rechazarla.

**¿Existe algun mecanismo para volver a revisar una edición sugerida o se puede cancelar esa aprobación?**

Comment: En base a esa pregunta si se revisa los comentarios de la respuesta, [el editor aclara que si puede complementar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86212/al-comparar-dos-booleanos-iguales-devuelve-verdadero-pero-no-al-comparar-dos-obj/86227#comment158803_86227), así que es considerada valida a mi parecer.

Comment: Si @JuankGlezz por eso no la revertí, aunque pienso que se podría haber generado otra respuesta para mostrar los ejemplos agregados.

Answer (score 4):

#### No

Una vez has apretado un botón que no sea "Omitir", tu decisión respecto un elemento de cola de revisión pasa a ser definitivo.

#### ¿Qué hacer si te das cuenta del error?

Antes de nada, recuerda que todos somos humanos y no te sientas muy mal por ello (por ser humano y por el error). Aun así, puedes hacer alguna cosa para intentar disminuir el hipotético daño producido:

- Deja un comentario indicando el error para que los siguientes revisores lo tengan en cuenta.
- Deshaz la edición.
- Reporta la publicación para que un moderador pueda acometer alguna acción.

Comment: muy importante esta aclaración: *por ser humano* xD

Answer (score 0):

Esa edición ya fue aprobada.

Las ediciones sugeridas no pueden ser revisadas nuevamente, pero puedes hacer un reporte personalizado pidiendo una reversión.

En tu caso, puedes editar directamente la publicación, según [el privilegio Editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Para este privilegio se requiere 2000 de reputación.

Si quieres editar tú mismo la publicación, puedes ir a lista de ediciones, y luego en donde dice **código fuente**:

[image: Código fuente.]

Entonces, luego copiar el texto, y editarla con el texto copiado.

Comment: Otra vez se modifico, pero esta cambiando el codigo original de la respuesta, no creo se deberia hacer eso, trata de agregar informacion util pero se aleja de la respuesta original.

Comment: @JuanPinzón Sí, entiendo, ahí dejé una imagen para editarla uno mismo.

Comment: Mas fácil sería revertirla, pero no se si sera buena idea hacerlo.

Comment: @JuanPinzón Si te aparece el botón para revertir, es mejor revertirla.

Comment: Desde hace poco, los moderadores y el autor de la publicación pueden revertir una sigerenciade edición una vez aceptada (o al revés)

Comment: @fedorqui Lo que no sé, es si lo que no son moderadores pueden revertir.

Comment: @arteze no, solo moderador y autor de la publicación. [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/209901)

Comment: Sólo un moderador o el autor pueden cambiar el resultado de una revisión, pero **cualquier usuario puede revertir una edición**, por lo que no corresponde emitir un reporte para eso, salvo que se requiera la intervención de un moderador para evitar una guerra de ediciones

Comment: @Mariano Bueno, cualquier usuario puede revertir, pero solo las propias, ¿o las de las demás también? En el caso de Juan Pinzón, ¿Puede revertir las ediciones de los demás?

Comment: @ArtEze claro que puede revertir cualquier publicación. Más info en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/127

Comment: Ah claro, revertir puede todo el mundo pues para eso está el enlace en el historial de revisiones, bien explicado @Mariano Yo me refería a revertir una sugerencia de edición, con lo que implica en el historial (pérdida del +2, etc)

Comment: @fedorqui lo sé, y de cualquier modo, no hay motivo alguno para copiar el código fuente (que además, para eso está el botón "editar" en el historial de revisiones)